# Get gCal:color from google api for java?

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to acquire the `<gCal:color value="xxxxxx">` value attribute from the Atom XML response in the google-api-java-client on Android. For some reason it isn't getting parsed, despite having a @Key defined for it. I can see it appearing in the actual XML response, but it's not parsed into the pojo properly.

Consider these pieces of code I've altered...

I added the gCal namespace:

```
AtomParser parser = new AtomParser();
parser.namespaceDictionary = Util.DICTIONARY;
parser.namespaceDictionary.set("gCal", "http://schemas.google.com/gCal/2005"); // I added this.
```

I added the gCal:color key to the CalendarEntry class:

```
@Key("gCal:color/@value")
public String color;
```

When I read the resulting CalendarEntry, the "color" String is still null.

No run-time errors occurring. A slight alteration, like "gCal:colors", would cause a HTTP 400 Bad Request. I was able to add @Key("id"), which works great, but none of the gCal stuff is coming back.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved...

I had to pull `gCal:color` and `@value` separately, rather than in one fell swoop with XPath..  ugh! time wasted on stupid shit, but that's ok..

So I created a class called ColorNode with a single key:

```
public class ColorNode
{
    @Key("@value")
    public String color;
}
```

And the CalendarEntry class then has a Key for the ColorNode:

```
@Key("gCal:color")
public ColorNode colorNode;
```